# SQL Server 2016 ERROR 4920 - ALTER TABLE {TableName} Disable Trigger {TriggerName} changing my table and trigger names

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am running into a weird problem with SQL Server (details below):  When I try to Disable/Enable a Trigger, it fails with MSG 4920, pointing at a different (but similarly named) Trigger on an existing, but different table in my database (which also has a similar name, but no triggers).

```
    SELECT @@VERSION;

    Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU6) (KB4488536) - 13.0.5292.0 (X64) 
        Mar 11 2019 23:19:30 
        Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
        Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 
            Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

```
    SELECT  LEFT(OBJECT_NAME(parent_id), 20) as TableName
            , LEFT(Name, 40) as TriggerName
            , OBJECT_ID 
    FROM    sys.triggers 
    where   PARENT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.ebHeaderSent');

    TableName            TriggerName                              OBJECT_ID
    -------------------- ---------------------------------------- -----------
    ebHeaderSent         ebHeaderSent_Insert                      240224852
    ebHeaderSent         trg_Write_ebHeaderSentDeleted_Record     1219444064
```

```
    SELECT  LEFT(OBJECT_NAME(parent_id), 20) as TableName
            , LEFT(Name, 40) as TriggerName
            , OBJECT_ID 
    FROM    sys.triggers 
    where   PARENT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.ebHeaderSentDeleted');

    TableName            TriggerName                              OBJECT_ID
    -------------------- ---------------------------------------- -----------
```

```
    SELECT  LEFT(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), 20) as TableName
            , LEFT(Name, 40) as TriggerName
            , OBJECT_ID
    FROM    sys.objects 
    WHERE   OBJECT_ID IN (240224852, 1219444064);

    TableName            TriggerName                              OBJECT_ID
    -------------------- ---------------------------------------- -----------
    ebHeaderSent         ebHeaderSent_Insert                      240224852
    ebHeaderSent         trg_Write_ebHeaderSentDeleted_Record     1219444064
```

```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.ebHeaderSent ENABLE TRIGGER ebHeaderSent_Insert;

    Msg 4920, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
    ALTER TABLE failed because trigger 'ebHeaderSentDeleted_Insert' 
                              on table 'ebHeaderSentDeleted' does not exist.
```

BUT...

```
    ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.[ebHeaderSent_Insert] ON dbo.[ebHeaderSent];

    Command(s) completed successfully.
```

AND

```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.ebHeaderSent ENABLE TRIGGER trg_Write_ebHeaderSentDeleted_Record;

    Msg 4920, Level 16, State 0, Line 20
    ALTER TABLE failed because trigger 'trg_Write_ebHeaderSentDeletedDeleted_Record' 
                              on table 'ebHeaderSentDeleted' does not exist.
```

BUT...

```
    ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.[trg_Write_ebHeaderSentDeleted_Record] ON dbo.[ebHeaderSent];

    Command(s) completed successfully.
```

ADDITIONAL EDIT:

```
    DECLARE @strSQL nvarchar(max) = '';

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.ebHeaderSent2;

    SELECT  * INTO dbo.ebHeaderSent2 FROM dbo.ebHeaderSent WHERE 1 = 2;

    SELECT  @strSQL = REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(Definition
                                    , 'ebHeaderSent', 'ebHeaderSent2')
                                    , 'ebHeaderSent2ID', 'ebHeaderSentID')
    FROM    sys.sql_modules SM
            JOIN sys.objects SO ON SO.object_id = SM.object_id
    WHERE   SM.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'ebHeaderSent_Insert')
            and SO.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.ebHeaderSent');

    EXEC (@strSQL);

    Command(s) completed successfully.
```

```
    SELECT  OBJECT_ID(N'ebHeaderSent2_Insert') as OBJ_ID;

    OBJ_ID
    -----------
    384225365
```

```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.ebHeaderSent2 DISABLE TRIGGER ebHeaderSent2_Insert;  

    Command(s) completed successfully.
```

```
    ALTER TABLE dbo.ebHeaderSent2 ENABLE TRIGGER ebHeaderSent2_Insert;

    Command(s) completed successfully.
```

Dropping and recreating the trigger does not correct the problem.

Comment: Good information! But the trigger definitions are are not provided above. Is it possible the trigger definitions them selves contain these "external" trigger references?

Comment: No, unfortunately they do not.  I'm going to add some information that I believe will show that the trigger definition is not the cause of the issue.

Comment: Maybe the triggers are "hiding" and your queries above aren't detecting them. Try broadening the search: `SELECT * FROM sys.triggers where Name like '%ebHeaderSentDeleted%';`

Comment: Good thought, but only the proper triggers are showing up, both in sys.triggers and sys.objects

Comment: OK your ebHeaderSent2 experiment is interesting but it seems like your issue is more subtle. I know you already said the existing trigger definitions do not contain the references. Do you mind if I ask how you know that? What method did you use to inspect the current definition of the triggers?

Comment: Well, the fact that ALTER TABLE {TableName} DISABLE TRIGGER {TriggerName) fails, but DISABLE TRIGGER {TriggerName} ON {TableName} works leads me to believe that it's not the definition of the trigger, especially given the experiment with ebHeaderSent2.  But, to answer your question, I visually inspected the Trigger code, and it doesn't even reference the failure TableName (ebHeaderSentDeleted)

Comment: Try dropping the triggers and `create` them anew.

Comment: Did that to no effect (dropping and recreating the Triggers)

Comment: I feel like the triggers you are being affected by are hiding somewhere and we just haven't found them. But, that's really all I can think of without getting into the destructive testing options like dropping and re-creating tables, etc.